# youtube-dl doesn't work after replacing the executable

Tags: youtube-dl, ascii

I' ve installed `youtube-dl` before; it works fine; but i have delete it and install another one following this commands:

```
sudo wget https://yt-dl.org/latest/youtube-dl -O /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

when i tried to download any video i got:

```
File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl", line 2 SyntaxError: Non-ASCII
character '\xe3' in file /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl on line 3, but no
encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for
details
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to download `youtube-dl` and use in this way. `youtube-dl` is in the Ubuntu repositories since 12.04 (Precise).

The current version for Trusty is `2014.02.17`.

Therefore remove `youtube-dl` in `/usr/local/bin` via

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

and install via

```
sudo apt-get install youtube-dl
```

---

To install a **newer** version, in this moment `2015.08.23` use a PPA

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install youtube-dl
```

If the `youtube-dl` is already installed and you only need an update, use

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: i've done what you have recommand (install from PPA), and i steel have the same problem

Comment: What is the output of `which youtube-dl` and `apt-cache policy youtube-dl`?

Comment: which youtube-dl ==> /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl

Comment: As I said in my answer, delete this file.

Comment: apt-cache policy youtube-dl ==>  Installed: 2015.08.23-1~webupd8~trusty1
  Candidate: 2015.08.23-1~webupd8~trusty1
  Version table:
 *** 2015.08.23-1~webupd8~trusty1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2014.02.17-1 0
        500 http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages

Comment: Simply delete the file `/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl`, read my answer

Comment: how can i remove; is this correct :sudo rm /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl

Comment: where can i find a good tutorial for youtube-dl

Comment: The `rm ...` command is correct

Comment: If I could solve your problem, just click the little grey **☑** at the left hand side of my answer, now turning it into beautiful green. If you like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow... If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask